# Render method aware which event handler/state change invoked it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use `onMouseDown`, `onMouseOver`, `onMouseUp` with corresponding methods (which all change state).

When only `onMouseUp` is invoked I want to apply some calculations on all rendered child components.

How can go about to do this?

Comment: can you paste the relevant code?

Comment: Unfortunately my code wouldn't clarify things. I'm just trying to understand how the control flow works in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you're looking for:

```
const SampleComponent = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            isMouseDown: false,
            isMouseOver: false,
            isMouseUp: false
        };
    },

    handleEvent( e ) {
        const eventType = e.type;
        this.setState({
            isMouseDown: eventType === 'mousedown',
            isMouseOver: eventType === 'mouseover',
            isMouseUp: eventType === 'mouseup'
        });
    },

    renderContent() {

        if ( this.state.isMouseDown ) {
            return ( <p>Mouse is down</p> );
        } else if ( this.state.isMouseOver ) {
            return ( <p>Mouse is over</p> );
        } else if ( this.state.isMouseUp ) {
            return ( <p>Mouse is up</p> );
        }
        return ( <p>default content</p> );
    },

    render() {

        return (
            <div
                onMouseDown={ this.handleEvent }
                onMouseOver={ this.handleEvent }
                onMouseUp={ this.handleEvent }
            >
                { this.renderContent() }
            </div>
        );
    }

});

module.exports = SampleComponent;
```